# Jquery each function not execute inside gridview textbox in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, aspxgridview

Here is my gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvDoctorVisits" runat="server" DataKeyNames="AdmissionId" class="tableStyle"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" EmptyDataText="No record found" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Amount" HeaderText="Amount"></asp:BoundField>
        <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="PaidAmount" HeaderText="Paid Amount"></asp:BoundField>--%>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Paid Amount">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPaidAmount" type="text" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PaidAmount") %>' CssClass='<%# "txtDoctorPaidAmount "+"txtDPPaidAmount_"+Eval("AdmissionId") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I am using j query each function of my gridview textbox class,but jquery each function not executing,here is my code

```
$(".txtDoctorPaidAmount").on('keyup change', function () {
    debugger;
    var sum = 0;
    $('.txtDoctorPaidAmount').each(function () {
        sum += parseFloat($(this).text()); 
    });
    $("#txtPaidAmount").val(sum.toFixed(2));
});
```

this each function not executing,how to solve this?

Comment: how do you know it's not executed? did you add an console log? 
don't use `jquery.text()` on input elements!

Comment: I debug this code,each function not executed

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Use `val()` instead of `text()` and add a `console.log` to see, if iteration is executed.

```
$(".txtDoctorPaidAmount").on('keyup change', function () {
    var sum = 0;
    $('.txtDoctorPaidAmount').each(function () {
        // use val instead of text
        let inputVal = $(this).val();
        // this line is just to show, that each is executed
        console.log('adding value: ' + inputVal);
        sum += parseFloat(inputVal);
    });
    $("#txtPaidAmount").val(sum.toFixed(2));
});
```